# calling facebox in a google maps balloon

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, facebox

I have a gmap balloon.

```
var marker = createMarker(point, '<div style="width:240px" id="mapsball"><h2>Splash of London</h2><img src="_assets/images/themes/shop.jpg" id="mapThumb" width="100" align="right" /><p>110-112 Hoxton Street</p><p>London</p><p>N1 6SH</p></div>');

    map.addOverlay(marker, icon);
```

and a facebox attached to the click event of the image ('#mapsball') which opens it in a facebox

```
$(function() {
    $("body").delegate("#mapThumb", "click", function(){
         jQuery.facebox('<img src="_assets/images/themes/shop.jpg" align="right"/>');

    });
 });
```

this works fine in ff and safari and chrome. but doesn't fire in ie.
I don't get a js error in ie so I am assuming it just doesn't get binded. any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also tried the following but the same result:

```
if (map.isLoaded()){
        $(function() {
            $("body").delegate("#mapThumb", "click", function(){
                jQuery.facebox('<img src="_assets/images/themes/shop.jpg" align="right" />');
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could it be related to the markup `<\/div>`?

Comment: as i said in my question. i do not get an error in ie. it just doesn't get binded.

Comment: somehow i think i need to wrap the code in something other than dom ready to bind when the maps is fully loaded? or? not sure

Comment: no the div is closed fine. dev toolbar shows. i did change to to normal closing and it is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried hard coding the event on the element (onclick="faceboxfunction();") and now it works.